# Can I use ext2 or ext3 formatted external SD card in Android 2.1

Tags: android

If I insert an external sd card formatted in ext2 or ext3, will it be
treated as a normal sd card (FAT32)?

The device is Samsung Galaxy S (Korean) running Android 2.1
I need the answer before I get the device tomorrow, because by the
time I get the device, I will not have any option to change anything
in the card.

Regards
Sarwar Erfan

Comment: ask android questions at http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It does not work :(
I tested on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S, Android 2.1) and found it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hint of a solution here for rooted phones:

http://android.modaco.com/content/htc-desire-desire-modaco-com/308568/how-can-i-bind-mount-e-g-system-sd-xxx-sdcard-xxx/#entry1511967

Comment: Thanks. But what I required is out of the box solution. My query was simple, if I buy a brand new device from  market and put ext2/ext3 formatted sdcard, will the device be able to read it. The answer is NO.